# Get all elements by class name with jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I get HTML page source in android and parsing it with jsoup. I want to get all elements with class name "den". But it just get first element whose class name is "den". How can I get all elements which class name is "den"?

```
public void onGetStringData(Document doc) {
    Elements newPrice = doc.select("a.den");
    String den = newPrice.attr("href");
    Log.e(TAG, "onGetStringData: " + den);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.select returns Elements you can do this

```
public void onGetStringData(Document doc) {
    Elements newPrice = doc.select("a.den");
    List<String> hrefList = newPrice
       .stream()
       .map(e->e.attr("href"))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Log.e(hrefList);
}
```

> Inhereted from java.util.Collection [docs](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It requires min. API level 24 but my min. API level is 19. How can I convert this code to API 19?

Comment: jsoup Java HTML Parser 1.12.1 API, I see this version on these docs can you add the docs from the API you are using?

Comment: I mean Android API level